# Clone Google Code Project

Tags: mercurial, google-code

When I try to download a project from Google Code using TortoiseHg I got the following message:

```
abort: 'svn' executable not found for subrepo 'mobile/ios/externals/google-toolbox-for-mac'
```

I am using this link [google.code](http://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/source/checkout)

EDIT: I am running Windows XP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The repository you're trying to clone as some [Subrepository](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) defined which are on a Subversion repository. The subrepository list can be seen in the [`.hgsub`](http://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/source/browse/.hgsub) file.

In order for the clone to work, you will need to install Subversion on your computer. You can find packages for various platform here : http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html

The executable must also be in the path so Mercurial can use it. Since you didn't give much details about your environment, I can't help you with that, but I think the installation process should take care of this.

FYI, Mercurial also handles Git subrepository, so if you want to clone a project which make uses of them, you will also have to install Git.

Comment: Thanks @krtek! I must have been quite frustrated by my incapability to handle this problem myself.